# Evalute $\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Evaluate the given expression $$\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}}}$$ The given answer is $\dfrac{1}{4}$. My attempt:
$$\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}}}=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n}\cdot2^4+2^{2n}\cdot2}}\\=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n}\cdot18}}=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{10}{9\cdot2^{2n}}}$$ This is as far I as I am able to reach. Thank you!

PS I don't see how one can get $\dfrac14$. For that we have to get something like $\sqrt[n]{A^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}=2^{2n}(2^4+2^2)=20\times4^n$,$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{20\times4^n}}=\frac14.$$

Comment: Thank you! Are we sure, though, that $\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{1}{\left(2^2\right)^n}}=\dfrac{1}{2^2}=\dfrac{1}{4}$ no matter if $n$ is even or odd? What restrictions should we put on $n$? Should it be a whole positive number?

Comment: Yes, and I have no idea about what makes you think otherwise. Just note that$$\sqrt[n]{\frac1{(2^2)^n}}=\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac14\right)^n}=\frac14.$$

Answer (score 2):

You made a small mistake :\begin{aligned}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}}}&=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n}\cdot2^4+2^{2n}\cdot2^{\color{red}{2}}}}\\&=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{20}{2^{2n}\cdot\color{red}{20}}}=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{1}{2^{2n}}}=\frac{1}{4}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity $\sqrt[n]{ab}=\sqrt[n]{a}\sqrt[n]{b}$, we find that
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{2^{2n+4}+2^{2n+2}}} &= \sqrt[n]{\frac1{2^n}}\cdot\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{2^4+2^2}}\\
&= \sqrt[n]{\frac1{4^n}}\cdot\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{16+4}}\\
&=\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac14\right)^n}\cdot\sqrt[n]{\frac{20}{20}}\\
&=\frac14.
\end{align*}
$$